# Permutation(?) mapping

Tags: group-theory, functions, finite-groups

Problem Statement:

> Let $G$ be a finite group, say a group with $n$ elements, and let $S$ be a nonempty
>   subset of $G$. Suppose $e \in S$, and that $S$ is closed with respect to multiplication. Prove
>   that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$. (HINT: It remains to prove that $G$ is closed with respect to
>   inverses. Let $G = \{a_1, \ldots ,a_n\}$; one of these elements is $e$. If $a_i \in G$, consider the *distinct* elements $\{a_ia_1, a_ia_2, \ldots a_ia_n\}$.

Incomplete Solution:

Let $G = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}.$ Let $a_i \in G.$ Then any number of $a_ia_1, a_ia_2, \ldots, a_ia_n \in S,$ since $S$ is closed under multiplication. One of those $a_ia_j$ is $e$ since $e \in S.$ Then either $(a_i)^{-1}$ or $(a_j)^{-1} \in S.$

To complete the proof I was told:

> You need to argue why one of them must be $e$. Show $f(x)=a_i \cdot x$ is an injection, then since it's a map from a finite set to itself that implies it's also a surjection.

Let $a_i \cdot x = a_i \cdot y$. Then $x = y$. So, $f$ is injective. Not too sure if that's correct, but I have a follow up question:

For $x = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n$; $f(x) \in \{a_i, a_i \cdot 2, a_i \cdot 3, \ldots  a_i \cdot n\}$. So, $f: \{1, 2, 3, ..., n\} \to \{a_i, a_i \cdot 2, a_i \cdot 3, ..., a_i \cdot n\}$. Is that correct? If so, how do we know $f$ maps from a finite set to itself?

Comment: Regarding $a_i⋅x=a_i⋅y \implies x=y$, that's correct because a group's operation is always [cancellative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property). Whether you're allowed to just state that or you have prove it too depends on what group properties you've been introduced to up to this point in your class/textbook.

Comment: And regarding your last question, I'm pretty sure you're told/hinted to *assume* that $f$ is from the group to itself. Otherwise what's the meaning of the multiplication it its definition $f(x)=a_i\cdot x$?

Comment: If $f$ is defined as $f(x) = a_i \cdot x$, then $f$ can't map a set to the same set, can it?

Comment: Why not? E.g., let $G$ be $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (with addition modulo 3 as the operation, i.e. $G$ is the [cyclic group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) of order 3) and let $f(x)=(2+x)\mod 3$. After that, try to see what happens if you make $f$ all the possible functions of that form by choosing another constant from $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ instead of 2.

Comment: I am not really following you. $a_i \cdot x \neq 2 + x$, right? Why are we redefining $f$?

Comment: Please state what is a group (in your understanding) and give an example.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. Turns out all the $G$s in the hint are actually $S$s. It's a typo from the old/international/nondescript edition(I got the PDF off the internet) of Abstract Algebra by Pinter(problem $5$, p.$50$ http://share.pho.to/8vHSM). This is fixed in the second edition.

Answer (score 1):

We suppose $S$ is a nonempty subset of a finite group $G$, which of course must be finite also. We know $e \in S$ and if $x, y \in S$, then $xy \in S$.  It suffices to show that if $x \in S$, then $x^{-1} \in S$.

Let $x \in S$ and define $f : S \to S$ by $f(y) = xy$. Notice that this is a well-defined map since we know $xy \in S$ by hypothesis. If $f(y) = f(z)$ then $xy = xz$ which means $y = z$ so $f$ is injective. Hence we have an injective map from a finite set to itself. This is also surjective. But by hypothesis, $e \in S$, so there exists $y \in S$ such that $f(y) = xy = e$ which means $y = x^{-1} \in S$.

Conclude by definition that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.